# How to wrap a remote schema in another query field?

Tags: graphql, apollo

Apollo `graphql-tools` now have Schema Stitching, which is great.
I want to merge multiple endpoints to generate a schema similar to [GraphQL Hub](https://www.graphqlhub.com/playground?query=%7B%0A%20%20github%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20repo(ownerUsername%3A%20%22facebook%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22react-native%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20twitter%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20user(identifier%3A%20name%2C%20identity%3A%20%22brunolemos%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A&variables=), like this:

`query {
  github: { ... } # GitHub Schema
  twitter: { ... } # Twitter Schema
  myOwnGraphqlSchema: { ... }
}`

How is the best approach to do that?

GitHub issue: https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools/issues/439

Fork here for testing: https://launchpad.graphql.com/3xlrn31pv

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

> EDIT: I believe this is now possible with the new graphql-tools 3.0!
>
> https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/the-next-generation-of-schema-stitching-2716b3b259c0

---

**Original answer:**

Here is a solution (hack?) I came up with, but probably there are better ways to do it:

1. Get the remote schema by using `introspectSchema` and `makeRemoteExecutableSchema`
2. Get the schema type defs by using `printSchema`
3. Rename the root typedefs `Query` and `Mutation` received by printSchema to something else, e.g. `GitHubQuery` and `GitHubMutation`
4. Create the root Query typedef with a `github` field with the type `GitHubQuery`
5. Create a `github` resolver that uses the `execute` method to run the `GitHubQuery` in the remote github schema

**Source code: https://launchpad.graphql.com/3xlrn31pv**

```
import 'apollo-link'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import {
  introspectSchema,
  makeExecutableSchema,
  makeRemoteExecutableSchema,
} from 'graphql-tools'
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { execute, printSchema } from 'graphql'

const link = new HttpLink({ uri: 'http://api.githunt.com/graphql', fetch })

async function getGithubRemoteSchema() {
  return makeRemoteExecutableSchema({
    schema: await introspectSchema(link),
    link,
  })
}

async function makeSchema() {
  const githubSchema = await getGithubRemoteSchema()
  const githubTypeDefs = printSchema(githubSchema)

  const typeDefs = `
        ${githubTypeDefs // ugly hack #1
      .replace('type Query', 'type GitHubQuery')
      .replace('type Mutation', 'type GitHubMutation')}

    type Query {
      github: GitHubQuery
    }

    type Mutation {
      github: GitHubMutation
    }
    `

  return makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers: {
      Query: {
        async github(parent, args, context, info) {
          // TODO: FIX THIS

          // ugly hack #2
          // remove github root field from query
          const operation = {
            ...info.operation,
            selectionSet:
              info.operation.selectionSet.selections[0].selectionSet,
          }
          const doc = { kind: 'Document', definitions: [operation] }

          const result = await execute(
            githubSchema,
            doc,
            info.rootValue,
            context,
            info.variableValues,
            info.operation.name
          )

          return (result || {}).data
        },
      },
    },
  })
}

export const schema = makeSchema()
```

Comment: OMG I love this hack.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on an example of how this is now supported in 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

Supported directly in graphql-tools-fork (https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-tools-fork) using the WrapType transform.

See https://github.com/yaacovCR/graphql-tools-fork/issues/24